# approve the class type of one object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple question about rails syntax:

How can I find out to which class a object belongs?

I try to do someting like:

```
if class(object) == MyClass
```

Thanks
Maechi

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do

```
if object.class == MyClass
```

or

```
if object.is_a?(MyClass)
```

The latter also returns true if `object` is an instance of a subclass of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 10):

```
object.is_a?(MyClass)
object.kind_of?(MyClass)
```

Returns true if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the superclasses of obj or modules included in obj. Aliased as ``

---

```
object.instance_of?(MyClass)
object.class == MyClass
```

Returns true if obj is an instance of the given class.

---

```
MyClass === object
```

Identical to `is_a?` method. Useful for case statements like

```
case object
when MyClass
when OtherClass
…
end
```